# Node Group separator for parameters

Tags: materials, node-editor, groups

Is there any way to add separators to better organize node group parameters?

Answer (score 3):

The hack I use produces node group 'separators' that look like this:

[image]

The techniques is to create an input by clicking on the '+'; changing the name to whatever you want as the visual separator and then selecting *Hide Value*.

Since you don't connect the input to anything it has no effect.

The downside of this approach is there's no way to prevent the user from connecting to the separator.

Comment: Nice solution Marty, thank you!